# Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF168E1657 (vcruntime140d.dll) in "<name>.exe": 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ipc, file-mapping

I tried creating two different visual c++ console applications for Inter Process Communication(IPC). The Build for both codes is successful.But,when I try to debug it, I get exception like this "**Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF168E1657 (vcruntime140d.dll) in FileMapServer_Parent.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000**"

```
//PARENT PROCESS:

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std
int main()
{
cout << "\t\t.....FILEMAPPING SERVER or PARENT....." << endl;
cout << endl;

//Local Variable Definitions


    HANDLE  hFileMap;
    BOOL    bResult;
    PCHAR   lpBuffer = NULL;
    char    Buffer[256] = "Hello From File Map Server";
    size_t  szBuffer = size(Buffer);


// STEP 1 : Create File Map

        hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(
            INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
            NULL,
            PAGE_READWRITE,
            0,
            256,
            L"LOCAL\\MyFileMap);


if (hFileMap == FALSE)
{
    cout << "CreateFileMapping Failed & Error Number - " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
else
    cout << "CreateFileMapping Success - " <<  endl;


// STEP 2 : Map View of File
lpBuffer = (PCHAR)MapViewOfFile(
    hFileMap,
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
    0,
    0,
    256);

if (lpBuffer == NULL)
{
    cout << "MapViewOf File Failes & Error No - " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
else
    cout << "MapViewOf File Success "  << endl;


//STEP 3 : Copy Memory Function

CopyMemory(lpBuffer,Buffer,szBuffer);


//STEP 4 : Unmap View Of File
bResult = UnmapViewOfFile(lpBuffer);
if (bResult == FALSE)
{
    cout << "UnMapViewOfFile Failed & Error No - " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
else
    cout << "UnMapViewOfFile FSuccess - " << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Exception while running parent process:
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bomQB.png

```
//CHILD PREOCESS:

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "\t\t.....FILEMAPPING CLIENT or CHILD....." << endl;
cout << endl;

// Local Variable Definitions

HANDLE  hFileMap;
BOOL    bResult;
PCHAR   lpBuffer = NULL;

// STEP 1 : OpenFileMapping

hFileMap = OpenFileMapping(
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
    FALSE,
    L"LOCAL\\MyFileMap");
if(hFileMap == NULL)
{
    cout << "OpenFileMap Failed & error - " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
else
    cout << "OpenFileMap success " << endl;


//STEP 2 : MapViewOfFile

lpBuffer = (PCHAR)MapViewOfFile(
    hFileMap,
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
    0,
    0,
    256);

    if (lpBuffer == NULL)
    {
        cout << "MapViewOf File Failes & Error No - " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "MapViewOf File Success " << endl;

//STEP 3 : Reading the data from File Map Object

    cout << "DATA READING FROM PARENT PROCESS--->" <<lpBuffer<< endl;

//STEP 4 : UnMapViewOfFile

    bResult = UnmapViewOfFile(lpBuffer);
    if (bResult == FALSE)
    {
        cout << "UnMapViewOfFile Failed & Error No - " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "UnMapViewOfFile FSuccess - " << endl;

//STEP 5 : Close Handle

    CloseHandle(hFileMap);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000*** Looks like you are dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Now it's time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). With a debugger you can catch crashes "in action" and see when and where they happen in your code. And also examine variables and their values.

Comment: Press break, search the reason.

Comment: You should exit if the file mapping fails.

Comment: I'm not an expert in visual C++. I'm working on a different platform. I just want to use a shared memory to avoid time overhead.I don't know what to do now.

Comment: BTW, Error code `3` from `GetLastError()` means path not found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try actually reading what is written on the console. What exactly do you expect to happen when you see these messages?

Comment: No. There is no Folder named like that.

Comment: It's just a name. It is not a path. It's the name for the page file for memory mapping.

Comment: But actually it's not a path I think. I just named it like that. see this syntax for create file mapping function : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry you are correct. I have always used this as a path to an existing file for the mapping. I am not sure why local is failing in this case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366791(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can anyone run the code?. I'm stuck in this. And also I'm not working in visual C++. I just need to use file mapping for shared memory.

Comment: I ran it. The error seems to be caused by capitalization. LOCAL must be Local. After fixing that it worked for me on windows 10.

Comment: Yeah It's working after changing "LOCAL" to "Local".Thank you so much :)

Comment: `if (hFileMap == FALSE)` will work but `if (hFileMap == NULL)` is more accurate.

Comment: I also put `return -1;` after `cout << "CreateFileMapping Failed & Error Number - " << GetLastError() << endl;`  to have the program exit if the mapping fails.

Comment: Thank you once again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
    NULL,
    PAGE_READWRITE,
    0,
    256,
    L"LOCAL\\MyFileMap");
```

From the documentation of Kernel object namespaces they are case sensitive so you must change `LOCAL` to `Local` for this to work.

***In addition to the "Global\" prefix, client processes can use the "Local\" prefix to explicitly create an object in their session namespace. These keywords are case sensitive.***

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx

While debugging this issue I also changed the code to exit if the mapping fails:

```
if (hFileMap == NULL)
{
    cout << "CreateFileMapping Failed & Error Number - " << GetLastError() << endl;
    return -1;
}
else
    cout << "CreateFileMapping Success - " << endl;
```

This avoided the crash with the original "LOCAL" (mapping failed).